# xamarin.forms autocomplete for visual studio

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

In visual studio 2015 with Xamarin, there is any option or plugin to enable autocomplete for attribut, something like that :

https://youtu.be/YgnuBub_o68?list=PLhr5vvvtqLQanFBxPw6KmgN1U43OONXX1&t=48

if you look at video, he have write **Text="{}"** then he saw suggestion list, I have already the plugin **"Enable XAML Language for Xamarin.Forms"** enabled, but I don't see this option to autocomplete for **Text="{}"**

Any ideas? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

the tool name is resharper, it integrate visual studio.